# Problems to upload a file from Angular 7 to Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm searching a lot but no question resolves my problem, I'm trying to send a simple image to a server in my Laravel 6.6 version.

This is my Angular 7 side

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[0]);

    this.categoryService.store(category, formData).subscribe(
      response => { console.log(response); },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

  public store(categoryData: CategoryModel, filesData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.mainConfig.config.default.mainUrl + this.STORE_CATEGORY_URL, filesData)
   .pipe(timeout(this.timeOut));
  }
```

And in my Laravel side, I just want to check if the file is arrive

```
    if($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Tem um arquivo";
        return $response;
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Não tem um arquivo";
        return $response;
    }
```

I found my problem I have a **token-interceptor** for every request for my API, that is like this:

```
  const newRequest = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
        },
        body: {
          ...request.body,
          companyCode: this.userData.companyCode,
        },
      });
```

When I remove this line

```
   body: {
              ...request.body,
              companyCode: this.userData.companyCode,
            },
```

It works fine, I use this to send the company code for my tenant database connection on the backend and in every request, I send the companyCode, but when i use this with formData is not working why?

Comment: try to get your file like this:
`$file = $request->file('image');`

Comment: When I try with postman my backend simple works, but when I go try with angular is not working =/

Comment: I found my problem i will edit my question plz look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem checking the instance of the FormData and now it is working

```
if (!!this.token) {
          let newRequest;
          if (request.body instanceof FormData) {
            const formData = request.body;
            formData.append('companyCode', this.userData.companyCode);
            newRequest = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
              },
            });
            return next.handle(newRequest);
          } else {
            newRequest = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
              },
              body: {
                ...request.body,
                companyCode: this.userData.companyCode,
              },
            });
            return next.handle(newRequest);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The upload should be always done using the `put` request on `httpClient` because file upload will be done in the smaller chunks(4kb). `post` can't transmit continuously and will only cut once the first chunk is transferred. You can directly use the `file` as the body. You should not use `FormData` for images because it appends the `FormData` headers and corrupts the image.

```
this.categoryService.store(category,this.selectedFile).subscribe(
      response => { console.log(response); },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
```

Modify the service as follows

```
 public store(categoryData: CategoryModel,selectedFile:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.mainConfig.config.default.mainUrl + this.STORE_CATEGORY_URL, selectedFile)
   .pipe(timeout(this.timeOut));
  }
```